# ¿Equals y HashCode? Java

Tags: java

Al no sobre-escribir `equals`, lo que hace este método es comparar el `hashCode` de las instancias?

¿Para qué me ayuda sobre-escribir el método `hashCode`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Toda clase en Java hereda siempre de la clase `Object`, la cual es la primera clase en la jerarquía de herencias. Es en esta clase donde se definen dos métodos que, en virtud de la herencia, todo objeto en `Java` puede llamar:

```
...
public native int hashCode();

...

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
...
```

**Respecto al primer método**, el objetivo de `hashCode` es devolver un número entero que 'identifica' al objeto cuando se guarda en una estructura de datos conocida como [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (u otros como [Hashtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)), cuyo objetivo es almacenar un conjunto de valores (de forma similar a un `ArrayList` o un arreglo). Estas estructuras, salvo algunas diferencias, persisten los datos de la siguiente forma:

[image: Hashtable]

Al querer guardar un objeto en esta estructura, se llama al método `hashCode()`, como mencioné, este devuelve un número entero, que la estructura usará para decidir en cuál 'cajón' (*bucket*) guardará este dato. Ahora, si quiero recuperar el objeto que guardé, llamo al método `hashCode` nuevamente, y así determino de cuál cajón debo recuperar el objeto (como cuando guardo datos llave/valor, llama al método `hashCode` de la llave para obtener el valor correspondiente). El objetivo de guardar los datos de esta forma y de llamar al método es lograr almacenar y recuperar información en tiempo constante (lo cuál no ocurre siempre, pero se acerca). El que no suceda esto depende, casi siempre, del valor que devuelva el método hashCode() para cada objeto.

Supongamos que guardamos 3 objetos en esta estructura y el método `hashCode` de los 3 devuelve 0, esto quiere decir que los 3 objetos se gurdarán en el cajón 0. Si quiero recuperarlos, ocurrirá que debo recorrer ahora los objetos que haya guardado en este cajón para determinar cuál es el que quiero. Por lo tanto, el método hashCode() de estos objetos no es útil, pues lo que se consigue es que al guardar los elementos estos queden dispersos de forma uniforme en toda la estructura (que queden la menor cantidad de cajones vacíos y que no haya cajones donde se guarden muchos más elementos que otros).

Respecto a la implementación del método `hashCode` de la clase `Object`, el identificador `native` señala que es responsabilidad del compilador determinar cómo realizará esta labor. En todas las implementaciones que he revisado, de forma nativa devuelve una representación numérica de la 'dirección de memoria' en la que se encuentra ubicado el objeto. Esta parece una buena estrategia por defecto, pero tiene un gran problema: hay muchas más direcciones de memoria que 'número de cajones' por lo que la estructura resuelve el problema (nuevamente, esto también depende de la implementación) asignándole el cajón número `hashcode()%MAX_LENGTH` donde MAX_LENGTH es el tamaño máximo del arreglo. Entonces, a mayor cantidad de elementos a guardar, mayor es la probabilidad que haya cajones en la estructura que tengan exceso de elementos.

Por tal motivo, si usted necesita almacenar elementos en este tipo de estructuras, `Java` aconseja sobreescribir este método. Algunos IDEs como Eclipse o Netbeans permiten generar un método `hashCode` a partir de las propiedades de la clase, y con eso es suficiente para resolver este problema.

**Sobre el segundo método**, `equals()`, la implementación por defecto de la clase `Object` es clara: compara referencias entre objetos. Así que no sobreescribirlo al definir una clase es una muy mala idea, porque no habría ninguna diferencia entre llamar a `equals()` y usar el operador `==`. La documentación es clara al señalar las características que debe tener este método al comparar:

1. Reflexividad: si comparo un objeto consigo mismo , debe retornar `true`.
2. Simetría: si comparo un objeto A con un objeto B y retorna `true`, entonces la comparación del objeto B con el objeto A también debe retornar `true`.
3. Transitividad: si comparo un objeto A con un objeto B y retorna `true` y comparo el objeto B con otro objeto C y retorna `true`, al comparar el objeto A con el objeto C debe retornar `true`.
4. Consistencia: si los objetos A y B no se modifican, llamadas sucesivas al método deben retornar el mismo valor.

Ahora bien, como se dará cuenta, el método `equals()` no llama al método `hashCode()`, entonces ¿por qué sobreescribir el método `hashCode()` cuando se sobreescribe el método `equals()`? la respuesta más sencilla es porque la documentación lo sugiere: si dos objetos son iguales, deben tener el mismo valor devuelto por `hashCode()`. A pesar de ser una sugerencia, nuevamente la operación en estas estructuras deja ver por qué es necesario: si dos objetos tienen el mismo hashCode, ambos objetos se guardarán en el mismo cajón, la estructura usa ahora el método `equals()` 
dentro de ese cajón para determinar cuál corresponde con el solicitado, y para eso depende de que usted haya sobreescrito el método, de lo contrario no garantiza un resultado correcto.

En resumen:

- Si sobreescribe el método `equals()` es recomendable sobreescribir también el método `hashCode()` para conservar el contrato entre ambos métodos: dos objetos iguales deben retornar el mismo valor de hash. El método `equals()` no llama al método `hashCode()` para determinar la igualdad de dos objetos.
- Es recomendable, por no decir obligatorio, sobreescribir el método `equals()` porque la implementación por defecto no es de mucha ayuda.
- Si dos objetos no son iguales, no es necesario sobreescribir el método `hashCode()`, incluso, dos objetos diferentes pueden devolver valores hash iguales.
- Si necesita guardar los objetos en las estructuras señaladas anteriormente (`HashMap` y similares) es absolutamente indispensable que sobreescriba el método `hashCode()`, de lo contrario obtendrá resultados inesperados o no deseados cuando realice operaciones de guardar, consultar o eliminar los datos.

Answer (score 2):

No. Lo que hace el método `equals` es evaluar si un objeto es igual a otro. Si una clase no sobre escribe el método `equals`, entonces el resultado del uso de `equals` será el mismo de utilizar el operador `==` entre los objetos. El método `hashCode` no está asociado al uso de la evaluación del método `equals`.

El método `hashCode` sirve para obtener un código hash que sería como un identificador del objeto. Este hash se utiliza en algunas colecciones como `HashSet`, `HashMap`, `LinkedHashSet`, `LinkedHashMap`, `ConcurrentHashMap`, entre otros. El hash lo que hace es ayudar al contenedor a ubicar el elemento en la estructura de la colección y ayuda a buscar si un objeto con dicho hash ya existe, esto para asegurar un tiempo de búsqueda O(1) (asumiendo que el número de colisiones es bajo).

Un ejemplo del algoritmo de cómo funciona `HashSet#add`, donde se utilizan los métodos `hashCode` y `equals`. (Es una idea, la implementación real es más compleja y utiliza más mecanismos para asegurar si se debe incrementar o reducir el tamaño de la estructura interna, pero eso no viene al caso)

```
//es pseudocódigo, no es código Java
//se utiliza una matriz para guardar los elementos
Object[][] conjunto = ...
metodo agregar (elemento)
    int hash = nuevo.hashCode();
    si (hash < conjunto.length)
        //pueden haber varios elementos con el mismo hash
        //por ello se utiliza una matriz
        //el hash ayuda a 
        Object[] elementosConMismoHash = arreglo[hash];
        var encontrado = falso;
        para cada Object actual en elementosConMismoHash
            si actual.equals(nuevo) entonces
                encontrado = verdadero;
                romper para;
            fin si
        fin para
        si no fue encontrado entonces
            agregar nuevo en elementosConMismoHash
        fin si
    fin si
fin metodo
```

Como puedes ver, el `hashCode` se utiliza como un identificador, pero pueden existir varios elementos con el mismo resultado de `hashCode`. Esto **no garantiza** que los objetos sean iguales mediante el uso de `equals`.

Comment: > "El método hashCode no está asociado al uso de la evaluación del método equals." Correcto. Pero, como dice la otra respuesta, es importante garantizar que si dos objetos son "iguales" (`equals` retorna true), entonces ambos deben retornar el mismo `hashCode`. Lo contrario, por supuesto, no es cierto (dos objectos distintos pueden retornar el mismo hashCode

Comment: Ambos deberían, no deben. Y eso es por el comportamiento en dichas colecciones.

Answer (score 1):

Por eficiencia del método `equals()` se suele comparar al principio del mismo los hashcode de los dos objetos, de forma que si no son iguales se retorna inmediatamente `false`, evitando el resto de comparaciones.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;

    MiClase other = (MiClase) obj;
    if (this.hashCode() != other.hashCode())
        return false;
    // Otras comparaciones
  }
```