# Método mas eficiente para comparar Strings y StringBuilders

Tags: java

¿Cual es la forma más eficiente para comparar **`Strings`** y para comparar **`StringBuilders`**?

```
cad1.equals(cad2); 
cad1.compareTo(cad2);
```

Después de comparar cualquier **`String/Builder`**, hay que hacer **`hashCode`** siempre?

Comment: Aunque ambos métodos sirven para comparar, tienen propósitos distintos. El primero sólo verifica igual, pero el segundo devuelve orden.

Comment: Gracias por responder. A que te refieres cn orden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque no entendí bien a qué apuntas, y aunque "eficiencia" dudo que importe en el 99% de los casos, al parecer `.equals()` es más eficiente, además que es más claro que `.compareTo(another) == 0` y evitás el odioso `NullPointerException`.

Acá tenés el source.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html

`hasCode()` no sé para que querés usarlo.

Y por si no te queda claro las diferencias, `StringBuilder` no es inmutable, a diferencia de `String`. Por lo que se aconseja usarlo en casos en los que quieras modificar strings morbosamente

Comment: Gracias por resolver mi duda. En cuanto al hashCode, dicen que sirve para volver a confirmar  una comparacion de objetos... de ahí mi duda.

Comment: Hola aquí una pregunta en la cual se explica mas a detalle el uso de hash code.
(https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5641/equals-y-hashcode-java)

Comment: @akarin volver a confirmar? Si this.equals(object) == true, DEBE  SER this.hashCode() == object.hashCode() .

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar objetos de String debes utilizar el metodo equals aunque debes tener cuidado al comparar dos StringBuilder con equals :

```
String cadena1 = "cadena";
String cadena2 = "cadena";

StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("cadena");
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("cadena");

System.out.println(cadena1.equals(cadena2)); //true
System.out.println(sb1.equals(sb2));//false
System.out.println(sb1.toString().equals(cadena1));//true
```

Al llamar al metodo equals de la Clase StringBuilder retornara false incluso si el valor de la cadena es la misma debido a que no sobreescribe el metodo equals() de la clase Objecto por lo cual comparara que ambas refencias apunten al mismo objeto

Espero te sirva
Saludos.

Comment: Puedes añadir la opción System.out.println(sb1.compareTo(sb2)) que devuelve?

Comment: Disculpa creo que ese metodo no existe en la Clase StringBuilder o por lo menos no lo pude encontrar

Comment: @Jose_Felipe_charbel_Pavez_Gass lo comentaba porque el autor de la pregunta preguntaba cual era la diferencia, debe ser que solo esta en el String ese método

Comment: Oka , ahora lo leo bien muchas gracias por la explicacion