# hashCode() me devuelve el valor del entero, no su hashCode

Tags: java, array

Tengo una matriz como esta, de la que quiero obtener los códigos `hash` de todos sus elementos:

```
Integer[][] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 3 }, { 1, 2, 3 },    { 1, 2, 2 } };
```

La recorro con un bucle y hago un `.hashCode()` de cada elemento. Pero en vez de devolverme un número identificador distinto para cada uno, me devuelve su valor  (en todos los 1s el hashcode es igual a 1, en los 2s a 2 etc).

¿Por que no me esta dando el hashCode?

Comment: El método `hashCode` de la clase `Integer` es simplemente el valor `public int hashCode() {return value; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El HashCode no es una identificador único de objetos en Java. Los HashCode deben cumplir solo 3 condiciones:

1 - No puede variar durante la ejecución del programa, siempre y cuando no se modifique la información utilizadas para comparaciones `equals()` del objeto.
  2 - Si dos objetos son iguales, de acuerdo a la utilización del método `equals()`, entonces el HashCode de ambos objetos tiene que ser el mismo.
  3 - Si dos objetos son distintos, de acuerdo a la utiliazción del método `equals()`, no es necesario que sus HashCode sean distintos.

Estos HashCode se utilizan para la optimización de operaciones de búsquedas, sobre todo en estructuras de datos que utilizan tablas de hash para almacenar sus elementos.

Y cómo se utiliza? Pues sencillo. Estas estructuras almacenan los datos agrupándolos según su HashCode. Determinando si el HashCode del objeto está dentro de un rango de valores, predefinidos por la implementación de la estructura. En dependencia de dicho rango de valores se determina en donde almacenar el objeto. De este modo, cuando se realizan búsquedas dentro de estas estructuras, utilizando el HashCode del objeto que estamos buscando se puede determinar en que sitio exactamente podemos encontrar dicho objeto, reduciendo considerablemente los tiempos de búsqueda/acceso.

Por lo anterior te comento que el HashCode no es para nada un identificador único de instancias de objetos, y que todas las instancias de un mismo objeto pueden perfectamente tener uno diferente cada una, excepto su son iguales según el método `equal()`.

Comment: Gracias por aportar , pero  la pregunta no fue sobre que era el hashCode , para esto puede pasar [por una pregunta donde se detalla esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5641/equals-y-hashcode-java/5649#5649). sin embargo no deja de ser positivo su aporte.

Comment: Disculpa, pero discrepo contigo. La pregunta demuestra claramente un error de concepto sobre lo que es el HashCode: **"Pero en vez de devolverme un número identificador distinto para cada uno..."**. Por este motivo entendí que lo prudente era explicar que es un HashCode, y esto no se puede hacer si explicar el objetivo de su existencia y uso.

Comment: Perfecto. No hay problema quizá me centré solo en la respuesta del por qué , Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Esto es normal en Java, la clase `Integer.class` , la implementación del método es simplemente el retorno de su valo.

```
public int hashCode() {
  return value; 
}
```

> Además en la [documentación de Java de hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode--) lo respalda ,
>   donde el valor retornado es el valor primitivo asignado.