# ¿Qué es HashCode en Java?

Tags: java, hash

encuentro en Java mucho código en el que se usan métodos **Hash**. Me he estado informando sobre estos pero no logro entenderlos del todo, ¿alguien podría explicarme qué son y su función en el programa? Se admiten ejemplos; si hacen falta más detalles ponerlo en los comentarios. Gracias por leerme.

Comment: `métodos Hash` pueden ser muchas cosas ¿Puedes poner algún código de ejemplo?

Comment: aquí en español esta la respyuesta a tu pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5641/equals-y-hashcode-java