# Por que al usar LinkedHashSet<> con un objeto en Java me duplica objetos?

Tags: java

necesito que alguien me explique el por que de la clase LinkedHashSet  cuando le mando un objeto si permite duplicarlos , y según lo que he leído no lo hace, claro el no duplica si utilizo clases como String o Int pero con objetos no pasa lo mismo.. aqui inserto el codigo

```
LinkedHashSet<Libro> hs=new LinkedHashSet<Libro>();
         
        //Creando  Libros  
        Libro b1=new Libro(12,"Oracle 10g Manual del Administrador","Kevin Loney","McGraw Hill",81);  
        Libro b2=new Libro(13,"UML para Programadores Java","Robert C. Martin","Pearson Prentice Hill",42);  
        Libro b3=new Libro(14,"Contabilidad Financiera","McGraw Hill","Wiley",61);
        Libro b4=new Libro(14,"Contabilidad Financiera","McGraw Hill","Wiley",61);
         
        //Agrgando Libros  hash table  
        hs.add(b1);  
        hs.add(b2);  
        hs.add(b3);
        hs.add(b4);
 
        
        System.out.println("Usando la clase Libro Duplica");
        //Libras
        for(Libro b:hs){  
            System.out.println(b.id+" "+b.name+" "+b.author+" "+b.publisher+" "+b.quantity);  
        } 
        
                System.out.println("\n usando String no duplica \n");

        
         LinkedHashSet<String> d=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
         
         d.add("A");
         d.add("B");
         d.add("C");
         d.add("D");
         d.add("D");
         d.add("A");

        System.out.println(d);
```

fíjense en la variable de tipo libro que declare como b3 y b4 el objeto tiene los mismos parametros , pero igualmente los imprime, de ante mano gracias a quien me ayude aclarando esta interrogante

Comment: De seguro no sobrescribiste el método `equals()` para la clase `Libro` y por eso no es posible saber cuando dos libros son iguales.

Comment: PD: También debes sobrescribir el método `hashCode()`

Comment: Gracias hermano por la orientación...!  Aquí dejo un link  por si alguien necesita saber más al respecto: 
 http://www.coderpanda.com/linkedhashset-in-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase LinkedHashSet no permite meter dos objetos iguales, pero necesita poder comparar los objetos de algún modo y, para ello, delega en los propios objetos introducidos. La clase Object tiene dos métodos que son:

```
public boolean equals(Object arg0) {...}
```

y

```
public int hashCode() { ...}
```

El primero es que es el que se usa para decidir si dos objetos son equivalentes. La implementación por defecto viene a ser algo como

```
public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
    return this == arg0;
}
```

Es decir, que dos objetos son distintos si no son la misma instancia. Por tanto, tu clase `Set` (da igual que sea un `TreeSet`, un `HashSet` o un `LinkedHashSet`, todas estas clases implementan la interfaz `Set`), cuando preguntan a b3 si b4 es igual, siempre responde que no. Es responsabilidad del desarrollador sobreescribir ese método para que pase a comparar los atributos o lo que considere oportuno.

Del mismo modo, el método `hashCode` debería ser sobreescrito para ser consistente con `equals`, por los motivos expuestos [en esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5641/equals-y-hashcode-java)